# How to compile a program from launchpad

Tags: compiling, launchpad, c

I tried looking through the documentation but I couldn't figure it out.  make and ./configure don't work so I thought I would ask here.

I'm trying to install this ( https://launchpad.net/livewallpaper ) on 13.10.  I've extracted it to /usr/local/src.  I've installed build essentials, checkinstall, cvs, mercurial, git-core, and subversion.

What terminal commands do I need to run to install it?

```
colton@Persistence:/usr/local/src/livewallpaper-0.4.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
colton@Persistence:/usr/local/src/livewallpaper-0.4.1$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
colton@Persistence:/usr/local/src/livewallpaper-0.4.1$
```

Comment: "make and ./configure don't work" <-- What is the error message you see? What did you try to fix the errors? Please include more about your attempts in your question. And why on earth are you building this yourself? There are packages available for this piece of software: https://launchpad.net/~fyrmir/+archive/livewallpaper-stable

Comment: @gertvdijk I'm compiling it myself because the ppa's do not work for 13.10.  I get 404'd.  As for errors I get "no such file or dir" when using ./configure and I get "No target specified" when I use make.

Comment: @gertvdijk I updated the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother using `make` yourself. The software source comes with a `debian/` directory which means you can build the packages yourself.

1. Install some basic build dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev build-essential bzr
   ```
2. Do a checkout of the code:

   ```
   bzr branch lp:livewallpaper
   ```
3. Go into the downloaded source:

   ```
   cd livewallpaper
   ```
4. Attempt to build the package:

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```

   As this is a plain source directory and no classic debian `.dsc` or `apt-get source` download you might see this warning:

   ```
   This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
   an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
   [...]
   ```

   Answer "y".
5. It will probably fail first with a line:

   ```
   dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: [...]
   ```
6. Install the build dependencies from the step above:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install [...]
   ```
7. Build again:

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```

   That will take a while.
8. Install the packages that were built:

   ```
   $ ls -al ../livewallpaper*.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert 966020 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  84242 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-config_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  45874 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-config-dbg_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert 142000 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-dbg_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  15744 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-dev_0.4.1-0_all.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  47258 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-doc_0.4.1-0_all.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  73196 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-indicator_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  13118 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-indicator-dbg_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gert gert  10680 Oct 16 01:32 livewallpaper-nautilus_0.4.1-0_amd64.deb
   ```

   Install them with `dpkg -i ../livewallpaper*.deb`
9. The above step might fail with unmet dependencies if you install the packages on another machine than you built them on. In that case, run `sudo apt-get install -f` to resolve them and it will finish the installation of the `livewallpaper` packages.

Comment: Thanks it worked.  Its a little glitchy on Gnome 3.10 but I wasn't expecting it to be perfect.  It was a fun process and I learned a lot.  Thanks!