# How to compile program source from launchpad branch

Tags: compiling, launchpad

I am trying to compile and [this branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~docky-core/plank/indicator-style) of plank.  I have some experience compiling software from git, but not from launchpad/bazaar.  I have tried following the instructions in the projects INSTALL and HACKING files, but both did not work.  I have also tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359622/how-to-compile-a-program-from-launchpad), but as the project does not have a debian/ directory, it did not work.  Any advice?

Edit: Here's the error when I run the commands given in the HACKING file:

```
parallel-tests: installing 'build-aux/test-driver'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Pick one of the recipes using it: https://code.launchpad.net/~docky-core/plank/trunk/+recipes?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no recipes using it.  However, I will try to write one, and see how that goes.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the output from what happens when you run the commands in `HACKING`: that is, `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr` followed (if that works) by `make -j2`.

Comment: Output in edit to post.

Comment: You don't have `autoconf`, `automake`, etc. installed?

Comment: Thanks.  That made the build almost work, but it still fails with a bad exit status.